# Why Quartz job is not getting executed(although QUARTZ tables are getting updated with proper job details)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Spring 3 with Quartz 1.8.6. I've defined SchedulerFactoryBean in the applicationcontext file in the following way:

```
<bean id="quartzscheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="autoStartup">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyClusteredScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="quartzdataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="quartzdataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/quartz" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

This is my job class which is beasically an entity bean class define in following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATABASEMONITOR")
public class DatabaseMonitor implements Serializable, Job {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public DatabaseMonitor(String name, String sqlQuery){
        this.name = name;
        this.sqlQuery = sqlQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("inside job");
    }
}
```

Here is my scheduler controller class:

```
public class SchedulerController {

    public static void addJob(DatabaseMonitor databaseMonitor){

        JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
        job.setName(databaseMonitor.getName());
        job.setJobClass(DatabaseMonitor.class);

        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
        trigger.setName(databaseMonitor.getName());
        try {
            trigger.setCronExpression("0/2 * * * * ?");
            Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) BeansManager.getInstance().getBean("quartzscheduler");
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And from main class I'm calling this scheduling function to add job at runtime:

```
DatabaseMonitor databaseMonitor = new DatabaseMonitor(new Date().toString(), "query string");
        SchedulerController.addJob(databaseMonitor);
```

Now the problem is that everything is working fine without any exception and job details are getting updated in the predefined quartz database details. But the job is not getting executed. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? In this way, It seems a simple "why it is not working" question to me.

Comment: Actually what I'm trying is to add task at runtime from the UI. It's working without any exception getting thrown but the task is never getting executed :(

Comment: Did you check whether the scheduler is actually running via `Scheduler::isStarted()`?

Comment: Yup....I'm using the scheduler instance defined in the Spring applicationcontext xml. And after checking it's showing true i.e. it's running

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you actually running a scheduler-cluster? Maybe another machine is picking the job and that's why you don't see an exception/output?

Comment: Maybe it is not getting scheduled correctly. You can use the code snippet here to see when the job is set to execute next (getNextFireTime()): http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-jobs-in-the-quartz-scheduler/

Comment: I am facing similar issue, have you got the issue?

Comment: @Jerry actually that was due to some configuration issue with respect to coding

Comment: Mine was memory issue , the running machine didn't have enough memory

Answer (score 0):

Your `DatabaseMonitor` should have a default constructor. Quartz is going to try to execute `JobDetail`. And `JobDetail` is going to create a `DatabaseMonitor` from scratch and executes its execute method. Since your `DatabaseMonitor` has no default constructor, it cannot be executed.

### Update

Since you have already have a default constructor, I would suggest a little refactoring. I am using 2.2.1 version of quartz with spring so some of the class names may be differ.

First lets break your entity into 2 pieces.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class DatabaseMonitor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SQL_QUERY", nullable = false)
    private String sqlQuery;

    // Getters && Setters && Def. Const etc.
}
```

I will explain job part later. And lets refactor your controller as a spring bean.

```
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl;
import org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.ParseException;

@Component
public class SchedulerController {

    @Autowired
    Scheduler scheduler;

    public void addJob(DatabaseMonitor databaseMonitor) {

        final JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
        jobDataMap.put("sqlQuery", databaseMonitor.getSqlQuery());
        final JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl();
        jobDetail.setName(databaseMonitor.getName());
        jobDetail.setDurability(true);
        jobDetail.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);
        jobDetail.setJobClass(DatabaseJob.class);

        try {
            final CronTriggerImpl trigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
            trigger.setCronExpression("0/2 * * * * ?");
            trigger.setName(databaseMonitor.getName());
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        } catch (ParseException | SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using JobDataMap to pass parameters to my job. This parameter is probably sqlQuery. And lets check our Job.

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class DatabaseJob implements Job, Serializable {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        final JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
        final String sqlQuery = jobDataMap.getString("sqlQuery");
        System.out.println("SqlQuery: " + sqlQuery);
    }
}
```

And I am reading my query from context. My job does not contains any state. In your implementation, your job is also an entity. Hibernate ( or other JPA implementations) proxies almost everything and holds a lot of state. This will interrupt with quartz execution.

### Update 2

I created an example application and put it to [github](https://github.com/bhdrkn/Java-Examples/tree/master/spring-quartz).

Comment: It has a default constructor which I forgot to add :( However it's not working

Comment: Idea based on this answer: Does the expected output/result depend on the parameters you give to the non-default-constructor?

Comment: @flo no it does not depend the parameters you give to default constructor. But since JobDetail takes jobClass as parameter, you cannot initialise an object instance if your class does not have default constructor.

Comment: @Abhinabyte do you get any exception? Could you lower the log level of quartz to debug and check log files for additional info?

Comment: @bhdrkn I'm aware of that; I thought maybe the OP relied on parameters he used while adding the job.

Comment: I perform debugging and found that scheduler is in running state and the job is getting added to the scheduler successfully. However, on the very next line when I'm trying to find out the all the job name associated with the scheduler it's throwing nullpointer i.e. no job is not actually in the scheduler. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Abhinabyte If you post code snippets I will try to help

Comment: I've already implemented the the code as you have suggested, I have one concern that is it due to versioning problem? I'm using spring 3 with quartz  1.8.6. Is this any issue

Comment: @Abhinabyte Class names may be differ from 1.8.6 to 2.x. I do not think versioning will effect job running. But is it worked? Do you have any problems? I can help if you have any problem. What about nullpointerexception you were getting?

Comment: Nullpointer exception is getting thrown when I'm trying to find the list size of the available job in the scheduler......that means no jobe is getting submitted to the scheduler and as a result nullpointer exception is getting thrown

Comment: @Abhinabyte I updated SchedulerController. And I tested it in a console application. I can put it to Github if the code above is not work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bhdrkn . Let me check the code and will let you know the result

Comment: @bhdrkn I tried to implement your code. However it's not working as the beans are not defined properly in the application context :(

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is missing mandatory
`org.quartz.threadPool.class` and `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` properties.

See:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool

Comment: If Scheduler created manually your are totally correct. SchedulerFactoryBean sets both of the properties by itself. You can check source code of [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context-support/3.2.13.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.java#SchedulerFactoryBean)